# Rviz open panel through plugin tool

Tags: c++, rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently developing a rviz plugin tool (myTool, inherited from rviz::Tool)  and a rviz panel (myPanel, inherited from rviz::Panel). They come together, so I want to open myPanel as soon as myTool is added to the tool bar in rviz. But I couldn't find a way to do it.

I am able to achieve the reverse. i.e. when I add myPanel through menu option in rviz, myTool is automatically added into the tool bar in rviz. This is done by the following code in myPanel.cpp

> vis_manager_->getToolManager()->addTool("myTool");

It would be nice if there is a similar way to open myPanel through code in myTool.cpp.

Or maybe there's a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240653/rviz-open-panel-through-plugin-tool/) by [ms0719584](https://answers.ros.org/users/27301/ms0719584/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `vis_manager_` has the `addPanelByName` function, see:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/115e9afe1b0a80e08cb7b2a7a3a97988e81bac94/src/rviz/visualization_frame.cpp#L1214-L1241

You'd have to figure out how to get the parameters, maybe look to the `openNewPanelDialog` function and the `NewObjectDialog` class for those:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/115e9afe1b0a80e08cb7b2a7a3a97988e81bac94/src/rviz/visualization_frame.cpp#L572-L591

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/0d423d6249a39f7f3ddd591007952c6dc940b6ac/src/rviz/new_object_dialog.cpp#L52

Sorry I couldn't be more specific, but I've never tried to do what you've described. I hope you find a way that works for sure.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ms0719584](https://answers.ros.org/users/27301/ms0719584/) on 2016-08-02**:
`vis_manager_` doesn't have `addPanelByName`. This member function is in rviz::VisualizationFrame. But I could only get its parent class rviz::WindowManagerInterface through `vis_manager->getWindowManager()`. I couldn't find any function that returns rviz::VisualizationManager.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-08-08**:
Hmm, you're right, I got those two mixed up. It might not be possible as-is. I'm sorry I don't have time to work something out for you, but if you find a way to do it, or have an idea of how it could be better organized, please open an issue on rviz.

**Comment by [ms0719584](https://answers.ros.org/users/27301/ms0719584/) on 2016-08-08**:
I find out I can get rviz::VisualizationFrame through casting: `(rviz::VisualizationFrame*) vis_manager->getWindowManager()`, but now the problem is `addPanelByName` is protected, so I cannot access it. There is a public function `addPane`, but it seems to create a empty panel,not an exiting one.